# What is wrong with my Dmux8way? How can I fix it?

Tags: logic-gates

[image]

The problem is something with the sel spliter and the leftmost
DMUX4WAY, the automatic check returned - "have different bit width and cannot be connected". But I don’t know how can I fix it.
Please help me with that.

Comment: Please draw a neat version of this circuit. It is not clear which lines are connected or just in the background, which makes spotting possible mistakes nearly impossible.

Comment: but am in the right way?

Comment: You need to reconsider what a DeMux does. Hint: Not all terminals of a device need to be used. (The diagram looks like logiccircuit.org - which version? Newer ones should colour networks connected to "pins" of unlike width in red.)

Comment: `What is wrong with my Dmux8way?` for me, it's your drawing. I can't see if there's something else.

Answer (score 0):

(0. Capitalisation is questionable: It should read *DMux8Way* in line with *DMux4Way*.)

Your <kbd>Sel</kbd> seems to be three bits (as it should) -
How many "sel-bits" does a DMux4Way need to demultiplex to 4 signals, and how many do you feed to each?

> Connected to the output terminals as depicted, *both* "output"-DMux4Way need to be fed the two low order <kbd>Sel</kbd> bits.

DMux4Way lacking an enable/select input, can you figure out what to feed to *in* of each "output"-DMux4Way?

> The *in* of the device connected to <kbd>q0</kbd> to <kbd>q3</kbd> should be <kbd>in</kbd> when the high order bit of <kbd>Sel</kbd> is 0, and not active when that bit is 1.
>  Can you figure out how to achieve that with gates/inverters?
>  Can you figure out how to achieve that using another DMux4Way?
>  Hint: Not all terminals of a device need to be used.